# GlassFish: list-commands gets me "requested resource is not available."

Tags: java, glassfish

Using `asadmin --port 8080 multimode`, I created and started a domain on the localhost; so far, everything is fine.  Then I try `list-commands`, and I get: `HTTP Status 404: The requested resource is not available.` If I try `list-commands --localonly` it works fine.  I completely took down my firewall to see if that was the problem, but that didn't fix it.

This wouldn't be such a big deal, since I can look up the commands elsewhere, but I'm getting the same error when I try to deploy a WAR file, and I'm guessing that both problems have the same cause (after all, `deploy` isn't listed under the local commands).

I'm using GlassFish 4.1

Comment: The default admin port is 4848 not 8080. Try it with `asadmin --port 4848`

Comment: That did it, thanks.